# How to export mysql data as xlsx?

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, typescript

How to export the data from mysql as xlsx, mysql workbranch only support export as CSV as i see in workbranch.
I wan to have some programme which can directly get an mysql stored procedures result as .XLSX format file. Any Idea?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python, you can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) to read the MySQL database into a dataframe and then export it to an excel file using the `to_excel` function.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -- You need to create the csv file first

```
import mysql.connector

db= mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='username',
      password='password',
      database="dbname")

cur=db.cursor()

QUERY='SELECT * FROM tablename;'

cur.execute(QUERY)
result=cur.fetchall()
path = "..."
result.to_csv(f"{path}.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `actor`.`actor_id`
,`actor`.`first_name`
,`actor`.`last_name`
,`actor`.`last_update`
FROM `sakila`.`actor`
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/actor.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'